# Python List output troubleshooting

Tags: python, list, tuples, output

I have a list as follows and trying to write it out to a txt file as tab delimited.

```
final_out = [(['2893541', 'OVERALL', 'friendly and genuine.'], 77), (['2893382', 'SPEED', 'timely manner."'], 63)]
```

My output statement is but it does not eliminate the square brackets:

```
fh = open("text.txt", "w")
fh.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % x for x in final_out))
fh.close()
```

My desired output is:

```
2893541 OVERALL friendly and genuine.   77 
2893382 SPEED   timely manner.  63
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use [`with`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) when opening files to automatically clean up your file handles.
2. You still end up with square brackets because you're converting a list to a string.
3. You aren't actually using tabs anywhere

My recommendation is to use the `csv` module, which will also handle escaping for you (by default using quotes).

```
import csv

final_out = [(['2893541', 'OVERALL', 'friendly and genuine.'], 77), (['2893382', 'SPEED', 'timely manner."'], 63)]

with open('text.txt', 'wb') as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh, delimiter='\t')

    for row in final_out:
        writer.writerow(row[0] + [row[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the write line like this:

```
fh.write('\n'.join('%s %s' % (' '.join(a), b) for a, b in final_out))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this approach:

```
final_out = [(['2893541', 'OVERALL', 'friendly and genuine.'], 77), (['2893382', 'SPEED', 'timely manner."'], 63)]
fh = open("text.txt", "w")

for final_out_item in final_out:
    first_part = '\t'.join(final_out_item[0])
    fh.write("%s\t%s\n" % (first_part, final_out_item[1]))

fh.close()
```

Comment: Note that the previous code it's not using any other additional libraries given the simplicity of the work done...